# I'm filling up an ArrayList of ArrayList<Integer> type . The insertion is done twice but the result reflects only the second update. Explain

Tags: java, arraylist

```
       ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
       int i=0;
       ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
       l.add(1);
       l.add(4);
       list.add(i,l);
       i++;

       l.clear();
       l.add(0);
       l.add(4);
       l.add(3);
       l.add(2);
       list.add(i,l);
```

Now my list has 2 elements with same value of {0,4,3,2} . What happens to {1,4} ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what is going on. `list` contains a reference to `l`.  So when you clear `l`, you clear the one you added to `list`.  But the reference is still there to accept new values.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
int i=0;
ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(1);
l.add(4);
list.add(i,l);
i++;

l.clear();    // you just deleted all the contents of list `l` but not the list `l` itself.
l.add(0);
l.add(4);
l.add(3);
l.add(2);    // now list `l` (the reference still in `list` contains 0,4,3,2
list.add(i,l); // and now list contains the same reference yet again so you get

System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[[0, 4, 3, 2], [0, 4, 3, 2]]
```

And note that if you do this, `list.get(0).set(1,99)` will affect both lists because each List `l` in List `list` is a reference to the same list.

```
[[0, 99, 3, 2], [0, 99, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: Note.  Unless you want to insert a value in the list somewhere, you don't need to specify an index to the add method.  The default operation is add the element to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of WJS is correct.

Just if you wonder how to make it work the way that you expect:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   int i=0;
   ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
   l.add(1);
   l.add(4);
   list.add(i,l);
   i++;

   l = new ArrayList<>(); //Remove l.clear(); and add new instance of the ArrayList
   l.add(0);
   l.add(4);
   l.add(3);
   l.add(2);
   list.add(i,l);
```

Not to be confusing  it is better you to make a new declaration with new name like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
int i=0;
ArrayList<Integer> listFirst = new ArrayList<>();
listFirst.add(1);
listFirst.add(4);
list.add(i,listFirst);
i++;

ArrayList<Integer> listSecond = new ArrayList<>();
listSecond.add(0);
listSecond.add(4);
listSecond.add(3);
listSecond.add(2); 
list.add(i,listSecond);

System.out.println(list);
```